# Setting Sass style to compressed in Sinatra is not working

Tags: sinatra, haml, sass

I'm having some issues getting Sass to output css compressed. I'm using a configure block in my **server.rb** file which sets up loads of things and I'm using the Rack verison

```
configure do
  ...
  use Sass::Plugin::Rack
end
```

So either side of this I've tried to following two options, separatly and together

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
set :sass, :style => :compressed
```

I've also tried setting these outside of the configure block, before and after. But nothing seems to be working, any ideas? I've tried restarting the server too. Driving me insane, any help would be great

Sinatra 1.2.6
Haml 3.1.2
Sass 3.1.7

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, try the following.

```
configure do
  set :sass, {:style => :compressed}
end
```

That works for me. Only difference I see is the hash so maybe that's why.

I also don't have `Sass::Plugin::Rack` I just require from Gemfile.